# Visual Studio + CMake + Qt Quick: как настроить отладку?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, visual-studio-2019, qtquick

Мой проект собирается с помощью CMake. Visual Studio может открывать CMakeLists.txt напрямую, без геренерации vcxproj, это очень удобно.

Так же в моём проекте используется Qt и QML. Если открывать vcxproj, то плагин к Visual Studio - Qt VS Tool позволяет в своих настройках подключить отладчик QML-файлов. А если открывать CMakeLists.txt, то Qt VS Tools не работает и отладчик приходится подключать вручную. Однако [официальная документация](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html) весьма немногословная - про подключения отладчика там лишь краткий абзац и тот содержит недостоверные сведения. Из этого документа совершенно непонятно, как собственно подключать отладчик для отладки QML.

Я попробовал сделать так как делает Qt VS Tools. Он передает параметры командной строки в отлаживаемый файл. Я попробовал передавать такие же параметры. В Visual Studio за настройки запуска под отладчиком проекта собранного в CMake отвечает файл launch.vs.json. У меня он получился такой:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyApp.exe (MyProj\\MyApp.exe)",
      "name": "MyApp.exe (MyProj\\MyApp.exe)",
      "env": "PATH=C:\\Qt\\5.13.0\\msvc2017_64\\bin;${env.PATH}",
      "args": [ "-qmljsdebugger=file:MyApp.exe,block" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Собственно за подключение отладки QML отвечает строчка `"args": [ "-qmljsdebugger=file:MyApp.exe,block" ]`. Эта строчка скопирована с той, которая генерируется в Qt VS Tools. Только вместо имени файла Qt VS Tool передаёт туда GUID проекта. У него эта строчка выглядит так: `-qmljsdebugger=file:{7A883E87-2CB8-3EB7-9DE4-156F3850167A},block`. CMakeLists.txt никаких guid`ов не имеет, поэтому непонятно что нужно передавать в параметре file. Документация утверждает что имя файла. Непонятно только почему Qt VS Tools передает туда GUID.

И файл собранный в CMake при запуске с такими настройками зависает в ожидании когда к нему подключится отладчик. Непонятно только как к нему подключать отладчик, ведь он уже запущен под отлачиком и отладчик к процессу уже подключен.

В общем сплошные вопросы. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно подключить отладчик Visual Studio для отладки QML файлов?

Comment: https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/10/08/qml-debugging-visual-studio

Comment: Внимательно прочитал этот документ. Информация там дана весьма расплывчато. Насколько я понял, как то можно подключится к одному процессу два раза разными способами и отладчик будет считать что подключен к двум разным процессам одновременно. Попробовал ещё раз подключатся два раза - не получается.